# Deploy Ionic app with AppFlow in a sub-directory?

Tags: ionic4, ionic-appflow

I have an ionic v4 app that is located in a sub-directory of a much larger mono-repo with various other Angular applications. The mobile app shares some typing files and some services with the other applications.

**I was wondering if there is a way to use AppFlow to build the mobile app as a sub-directory of a larger repo or does it need to be it's own repo?**

Comment: So far I haven't found a solution other than ripping out the ionic directory and deploying it separately. Obviously this is not ideal...I had to also bring over the shared types and services. I've also reached out to the Ionic team to see if they offer a solution and I will post here if I find any better alternative.